# How can I trigger an event on an element that is dynamically created?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an Etch-A-Sketch project. I've dynamically created a 16x16 grid, the squares change colour on mouseover. When the reset button is clicked, I want the squares to turn back to white again, however I keep getting the error "Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined". Any hints are appreciated.

```
/*****Create grid *****/
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const row = document.createElement("div");
grid.appendChild(row);
for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    const column = document.createElement("div");

    column.style.height = "20px";
    column.style.width = "20px";
    column.style.border = "solid black 2px";
    column.classList.add("row");

    grid.appendChild(column);
};
};

/*****Random color picker for grid square*****/
let gridSquare = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

gridSquare.forEach(function (item) {
item.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    const hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
    let hexColour = "#";
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        hexColour += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length)];
    };
    item.style.backgroundColor = hexColour;
});
});

/*****Reset button******/
const resetButton = document.querySelector(".reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
gridSquare.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
```

Comment: You may use a container div to contain all the elements and then use event delegation https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through each square created.. the `document.querySelectorAll(".row");` return an `array` so basically you tried to set the background to an array, which is not possible

```js
/*****Create grid *****/
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  const row = document.createElement("div");
  grid.appendChild(row);
  for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    const column = document.createElement("div");

    column.style.height = "20px";
    column.style.width = "20px";
    column.style.border = "solid black 2px";
    column.classList.add("row");

    grid.appendChild(column);
  };
};

/*****Random color picker for grid square*****/
let gridSquare = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

gridSquare.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    const hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
    let hexColour = "#";
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      hexColour += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length)];
    };
    item.style.backgroundColor = hexColour;
  });
});

/*****Reset button******/
const resetButton = document.querySelector(".reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  gridSquare.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  })

});
```

```html
<button class="reset"> reset </button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your grid squares when reset is clicked.

```
/*****Reset button******/
const resetButton = document.querySelector(".reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   gridSquare.forEach( function(item) { 
     item.style.backgroundColor = "white";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the gridSquare contains multiple document elements as you specified `querySelectorAll` when defining the variable gridSquare.The `style.backgroundColor` only works for one element so what you could do is iterate through the `gridSquare` variable and change the style just like below:

```
resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    gridSquare.forEach(function(square) {
        square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    })
});
```